# datagrid with checked checkboxes

Tags: java, javascript

I have the following datagrid with a checkbox:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="dgExpenditures"  runat="server" Width="676px" PageSize="15"  
<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="AliceBlue"></AlternatingItemStyle>
<HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="Silver"></HeaderStyle>
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Mark To Edit">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" Runat="server" CssClass="Chkbx" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="RecordID" DataField="Record ID" SortExpression="Record ID" 
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="PSN" DataField="PSN" SortExpression="PSN" />
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Dist#" DataField="Dist" SortExpression="Dist" />
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Line#" DataField="Line" SortExpression="LineNum" />
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Gross Amt" DataField="GrossAmt" SortExpression="GrossAmt" />
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Rate(%)" DataField="Rate" SortExpression="Rate" />
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Net Amt" DataField="NetAmt" SortExpression="NetAmt"  />
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

I also have a delete button on the page that when selected will delete the records that are checked by looping through the grid and deleting those that are checked. This loop is in the button.click event.

I have added a script function to the .aspx page that pops a confirm dialog, but it will appear if no items are selected. I only want it to appear if 1 or more checkboxes have been selected in the data grid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function beforeDelete() {
    return $('.Chkbx').is(':checked') && confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');

}
</script>
```

So my problem is how do I write a java function to loop through the datagrid to see if there are checkboxs checked?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my return slightly to read

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function beforeDelete() {
            var n = $('input:checked').length;
            return n > 0 && confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');
        }

</script>
```